# Should/must I allow Dynamic Updates on _msdcs.<fqdn>?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have two W2k8 DCs in two subnets which are in different AD sites. A short time ago, I experienced the problem that the _msdcs forward lookup zone was empty - the reason is still unclear to me. Restarting netlogon seems the standard way of re-creating the DC records, but it did not succeed. After some time I found out that Dynamic Updates have been disabled on _mdscs, and when I set it to "Secure only", the entries were re-created. However, I also found several internet sources saying that Dynamic Updates does not need to be enabled for _msdcs. Therefore, I am interested in what the recommended settings for the _msdcs zone are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself: AD can only work correctly if dynamic updates are allowed.